# Jquery carousel blinking image issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've managed to create a jquery carousel. However when the previous button is pressed, the image blinks before loading. I understand that its due to the list not having the previous image loaded before its accessed. Is there a way to preload it always? How do the infinite scrolling carousels do it? I hope someone can help.

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){

    var interval = setInterval(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
    $(this).find('li:last').after($(this).find('li:first'));
    $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    })
  },5000);


  $('#next').click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:-480},1000,function(){
         $(this).find('li:last').after($(this).find('li:first'));
         $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('#prev').click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:480},1000,function(){
         $(this).find('li:first').before($(this).find('li:last'));
         $(this).css({marginLeft:0});
    });
    return false;
  });

});
</script>
```

This is my jfiddle with the sample.

https://jsfiddle.net/amosangyongjian/4jan3t10/

Comment: Check this demo if it helps you -- http://fiddle.jshell.net/webninjataylor/R79Ma/light/

Comment: It does, but each div is assigned to each image. Mine is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not so much one of loading but one that there is no image to the left of the viewport. You have all your images float left and on #next are simply sliding them left 'behind' the viewport. But then you go the other way there is actually nothing there so you are shifting blank space then using css to place the desired image there.

The solution is to shift your viewport so that its looking at the 2nd image in a row of images. Then you always have something on both sides:

So we shift viewport 480px;

```
#carousel ul{         
  width:1920px;
  padding:0;
  margin:0 0 0 -480px; 
}
```

Then we adjust code accordingly:

```
$('#next').click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft:-960},1000,function(){
       $(this).find('li:last').after($(this).find('li:first'));
       $(this).css({marginLeft:-480});
    });
    return false;  
  });

$('#prev').click(function(){
    $('#carousel ul').animate({marginLeft : 0}, 1000, function(){
    $(this).find('li:first').before($(this).find('li:last'));
    $(this).css({marginLeft : -480});
    });
    return false;   
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cyberwombat/4jan3t10/14/

Comment: Hello, I was wondering how I would go about linking to specific images?

Comment: What do you mean by linking?